# Why I am getting setId() undefined

Tags: android

When I use `setId(D)`, I get this error message:

```
The method setId() is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

If I cannot use `setId()` in this case, is there any other way to set an ID for the `TextView` dynamically?

**MainActivity:**

```
...
public void onClick(View view) {
  ...
  if (D>=0) {screen();}
  D=D+1;
}

public void screen()  {
  setId(D);
  if (D==0) {
    TextView D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.D);
    D.setText("the button was pressed: " +D+ "time");
  }
}
...

// I dont want to write twenty conditions
if (D==1) {
    TextView D1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.1);      
    D1.setText("some text" +num);
    }       
if (D==2) {
    TextView D2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.2);      
    D2.setText("some text" +num) ;
    }
if (D==3) {
    TextView D3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.3);      
    D3.setText("some text" +num) ;
    }
// and so on...
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<TextView        
  android:id="@+id/1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<TextView        
  android:id="@+id/2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

...
```

Comment: Because `Activity` doesn't have a `setId()` method. You need to use that on a `View` or similar. Looking at your code, though, I'm confused about what you're doing. An id shouldn't be used as a counter.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It will not be a counter it was shortened . Every TextView will be filled out by text and numbers depending on another algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

ID are not meant to change or to be used as variable. For a meta data that is attached to a view, you may want to have a look at view.tag http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()

you can also retrieve a view by tag. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)

Note that there is other way to store a counter. Usually a simple field in your activity is enough.

Comment: thank you. As I wrote to James I would like to get text and numbers which will be changed dynamically depending on another function. The result (text/numbers) should be shown on the screen one by one for example ten lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
public void onClick(View view) {          
...          
      // pass the clicked view
      if (D>=0) {screen(view);}                
      D=D+1;            
}   

public void screen(View view)  {
    /// call setId on the view that was clicked      
    view.setId(D); 
    if (D==0) {  //  maybe you want !=0 here instead
        // D already should exist as a number,  notice the name change in next 2 line
        TextView textview_D = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.D);       
        textview_D.setText("the button was pressed: " +D+ "time");
     }
} 
...
```

Comment: It looks that it could work. The "undefined getId()" disappeared  but I am getting another error: "D cannot be resolved or is not a field" . Thanks

Comment: im not sure where `D` comes from in your code,  however  its best to use `textview_D` instead of another `D` (see edit)

Comment: the D should be a reference for the ID of TextView something like:       if D=1 execute  TextView with android:id="@+id/1"     if D=2 execute  TextView with android:id="@+id/2"